# C# Language Question: priority of matching

Tags: c#

I'm reading book "C# Language", and hit this example from Page 123-124:

The meaning of a name within a block may differ based on the context in which the name is used.

In the example

```
using System;
class A { }
class Test
{
  static void Main()
  {
    string A = "hello, world";
    string s = A; // Expression context
    Type t = typeof(A); // Type context
    Console.WriteLine(s); // Writes "hello, world"
    Console.WriteLine(t); // Writes "A"
  }
}
```

the name A is used in an expression context to refer to the local variable A and in a type
context to refer to the class A.

I'm fine with the visibility of class A. However, here (`Type t = typeof(A)`) class `A` preceded string `A`.
So, what is the "priority" or "sequence" of matching/choosing a possible "A"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no conflict.  `typeof` only works on class names.  To get the Type of an object instance, you use `.GetType()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string A = "hello, world";
string s = A; // Expression context
A a=new A();
Type t = typeof(A); // Type context
Console.WriteLine(s); // Writes "hello, world"
Console.WriteLine(t); // Writes "A"
```

Here we see one example of an expression context: `string s = A`. In the expression context the local variable takes precedence over the class.

When a type context is used:

- Inside `typeof(A)`
- When declaring a variable `A a = ...`
- After the `new` keyword: `new A()`

Only the type is considered. Since in that context `A` referring to a variable would result in invalid grammar its clear that the type is meant and thus the specification allows it.

One case where the rule is a bit annoying is when you want to refer to a static member of the class. For example `A.CallStaticMethod()`. Here you have an expression context and it refers to the variable `A` and not the class `A`.

Comment: hmmmm, after type it in and read the book again I finally understood the A.CallStaticMethod() thing. it will  has compilation error as A is recognized as string, and string has no CallStaticMethod(). class A is hidden in this example.